# Passing form's input to Parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I am playing around a bit with Parse.com and I am trying to send HTML form's content to Parse.com
I am kind of a Javascript noob so for some reason I cannot find a way to pass a variable I got from the form's input to Parse.com for processing.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="main">
<form action="">
<label>Insert your ingridient :</label>
<input type="text" id="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="button" id="text_value" value="Get Value"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#text_value').click(function() {
    var text_value = $("#text").val();{
    alert(text_value);
        }
    });
});

Parse.initialize("myAPIKey", "myAPIKey");
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var gameScore = new GameScore();


    gameScore.save({
        name: text_value,
            }, {
        success: function(gameScore) {
        // The object was saved successfully.
        },
        error: function(gameScore, error) {
        // The save failed.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
  }
});
  </script>
```

Comment: for starters, remove the `{` and `}` from around your `alert(text_value)`...

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the code that does the saving inside a function, then call it when the user clicks the button. You have a few errors with your {} brackets as well. Indenting your code when writing it will help you avoid that.

```
<div class="main">
<form action="">
<label>Insert your ingridient :</label>
<input type="text" id="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="button" id="text_value" value="Get Value"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text_value').click(function() {
            var text_value = $("#text").val();
            save(text_value);
        });

        Parse.initialize("myAPIKey", "myAPIKey");
        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
        var gameScore = new GameScore();

        function save(value) {
            gameScore.save({name: text_value}, {
                success: function(gameScore) {
                    // The object was saved successfully.
                },
                error: function(gameScore, error) {
                    // The save failed.
                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                }
            });
        };
    };
</script>
```